# How to display multiple background colors in a chart?

Tags: python, graph, charts, background

I am trying to plot a performance diagram and I would like to have certain sections of it be different colors based on the CSI value.

I am able to plot a performance diagram with an all white background so far.

```
    line_label=[]
    line_str=[]
    line_label2=[]
    line_str2=[]
    ax  = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    x     = np.arange(0,1.01,0.01)
    y     = np.arange(0,1.01,0.01)
    xi,yi = np.meshgrid(x, y)
        #Calculate bias and CSI; set contour levels
    bias  = yi/xi
    blevs = [0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 2.5, 5, 10]
    csi   = 1/( (1/xi) + (1/yi) - 1 )
    csilevs = np.arange(0.1,1,0.1)

    #Axis labels, tickmarks
    ax.set_xlabel('Success Ratio (1 - False Alarm Ratio)',fontsize=16,fontweight='bold',labelpad=30)
    ax.set_ylabel('Probability of Detection',fontsize=16,fontweight='bold')
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1))
    ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,1.1,0.1))
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(),fontsize=13)
    plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(),fontsize=13)
                        #Second y-axis for bias values < 1
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.set_yticks(blevs[0:5])
    plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(),fontsize=13)

    #Axis labels for bias values > 1
    ax.text(0.1,1.015,'10',fontsize=13,va='center',ha='center')
    ax.text(0.2,1.015,'5',fontsize=13,va='center',ha='center')
    ax.text(0.4,1.015,'2.5',fontsize=13,va='center',ha='center')
    ax.text(0.8,1.015,'1.25',fontsize=13,va='center',ha='center')

    #Plot bias and CSI lines at specified contour intervals
    cbias =  ax.contour(x,y,bias,blevs,colors='black',linewidths=1,linestyles='--')
    ccsi  =  ax.contour(x,y,csi,csilevs,colors='gray',linewidths=1,linestyles='-')
    plt.clabel(ccsi,csilevs,inline=True,fmt='%.1f',fontsize=14,fontweight='bold')
```

This is current result
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5DWa.jpg.
I want different colors between the gray, curved lines that go from 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
ax.contourf(x,y,csi, np.r_[0, csilevs, 1],linestyles='-')
```

before `cbias = ...`

The `np._r` adds levels at 0 and 1 so they are filled too

[image: figure]

Comment: Yes this is what I was going for.  Where are the colors controlled from though in that statement?

Comment: Use `cmap` to choose the colour map e.g. `cmap="Blues"`. See https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html to choose one

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I've used cmap before but I do not see a reference to a cmap in the code line you posted.  Would it go something like this: 
cmap="Blues"...ax.contourf(x,y,csi, np.r_[0, csilevs, 1],linestyles='-',color=cmap)

Comment: It's an argument to `contourf`, so something like ax.contourf(x,y,csi, np.r_[0, csilevs, 1],linestyles='-', cmap='Blues')

Comment: Thank you, I got it working now!  Appreciate the help.